# Does exercising in cold burn more calories?

Tags: calories, daily-caloric-intake, cold

My thoughts are that in winter, especially outdoors winter exercising should burn more calories. It takes more energy to heat up the body for so long.

I feel when I eat quite a lot in a day I feel warmer, and when I restrict calories I'm pretty much colder.

Should you up your calories on winter? Especially if exercising outdoors.

Comment: http://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2014/02/how-being-cold-burns-calories/283810/

Comment: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1199264/

Answer (score 0):

Even if being cold in general increases your metabolism, because you need to burn more energy to be warm, it's not necessarily so that exercise in cold uses more calories. You'll be warm anyway, so to speak. If it hadn't been cold, you would have sweated instead, which you will probably do, but to a lower extent, in cold.